# The benefits of sentry in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to put together a little tutorial to demonstrate the benefits of using a sentry node when creating a linked list. Target audience is novices that already tried to make a linked list. Any kind of feedback, regarding best practices, readability etc appreciated.

```
// 2014 donated to Public Domain

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// linked list using sentry

// this could be anything
typedef struct
{
    int val; // here is where you change what this is a list of
} Data;

// this will be our Node, the items in the linked list
typedef struct NodeTag
{
    struct NodeTag* next;
    struct NodeTag* prev;
    Data data;
} Node;

// this will be out sentry node
// more later on why this is a good idea
typedef struct SentryTag
{
    struct NodeTag* next;
    struct NodeTag* prev;
} Sentry;

// this is the 'container'
typedef struct
{
    Node* sentry; // node that sentry 'poses' as a node, saves most casting
    int size;
} List;

// this creates a new empty list
void ListInit( List* lst )
{
    lst->sentry = (Node*) malloc( sizeof(Sentry) ); // make a new sentry node
    lst->sentry->next = lst->sentry;
    lst->sentry->prev = lst->sentry; // that points to itself
    lst->size = 0;
}

// pointer to first item of list, or end if empty
Node* ListBegin( List* lst )
{
    return lst->sentry->next; // no special-cases for empty list needed when using sentry
}

// pointer to end (one past last)
Node* ListEnd( List* lst )
{
    return lst->sentry; // no special-cases for empty list needed when using sentry
}

// now we have what we need for iterating through the list
// this is how you do it:
//
// Node* iter = ListBegin(lst);
// while( iter != ListEnd(lst) ) {
//     DoSomething( iter->data );
//     iter = iter->next;
// }

// this inserts new data before 'here'
Node* ListInsert( List* lst, Node* here, Data* data )
{
    // create new item
    Node* item = (Node*) malloc( sizeof(Node) );
    // copy in data
    memcpy( &item->data, data, sizeof(Data) );
    // link node
    item->prev = here->prev;
    item->next = here;
    // link the list
    item->prev->next = item;
    item->next->prev = item;
    // no special cases needed when using sentry
    // update size
    lst->size += 1;
    return item;
}

// adds new item last
void ListPushBack( List* lst, Data* d )
{
    ListInsert( lst, ListEnd(lst), d );
}

// adds new item first
void ListPushFront( List* lst, Data* d )
{
    ListInsert( lst, ListBegin(lst), d );
}

// now we can add items to the list, lets remove them

// erase one item. don't call for end
Node* ListErase( List* lst, Node* here )
{
    // save next item for return value
    Node* nxt = here->next;
    // unlink item. no special cases needed for empty list when using sentry
    here->prev->next = here->next;
    here->next->prev = here->prev;
    // delete item
    free(here);
    // update size
    lst->size -= 1;
    return nxt;
}

// this is how you iterate a list, while deleting some items that fulfils some criteria:
//
// Node* iter = ListBegin(lst);
// while( iter != ListEnd(lst) ) {
//     DoSomething( iter->data );
//     if( SomeCriteria( iter->data ) )
//         iter = ListErase( lst, iter );
//     else
//         iter = iter->next;
// }

// remove last item. don't call on empty list
void ListPopBack( List* lst )
{
    ListErase( lst, ListEnd(lst) );
}

// remove first item. don't call on empty list
void ListPopFront( List* lst )
{
    ListErase( lst, ListBegin(lst) );
}

// and a way to clear the list

// erase all items
void ListClear( List* lst )
{
    Node* p = lst->sentry->next;
    Node* n;
    while( p != lst->sentry )
    {
        n = p->next;
        free(p);
        p = n;
    }
    lst->size = 0;
}

// this destroys the list itself
void ListDelete( List* lst )
{
    ListClear(lst);
    free(lst->sentry);
    lst->sentry=0;
}

// a few convenience functions

// returns size of list
int ListSize( List* lst )
{
    return lst->size;
}

// returns true if list empty
bool ListEmpty( List* lst )
{
    return lst->sentry->next == lst->sentry;
}

// and now we have most we need for a linked list :D

bool ListIntegrityCheck( List* lst )
{
    if(!lst) return false;
    if(!lst->sentry) return false;
    Node* prev = lst->sentry;
    Node* curr = lst->sentry->next;
    int sz = 0;
    while( curr != lst->sentry )
    {
        ++sz;
        if( curr->prev != prev ) return false;
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if( sz != lst->size ) return false;
    if( lst->sentry->prev != prev ) return false;

    return true;
}


char* TestList()
{
    static char buffer[256];
    static char str[256];

    List list;

    ListInit(&list);

    Data d = { 0 } ;
    ++d.val; ListPushBack( &list, &d );
    ++d.val; ListPushBack( &list, &d );
    ++d.val; ListPushBack( &list, &d );
    ++d.val; ListPushBack( &list, &d );

    // list should be 1, 2, 3, 4

    Node* iter = ListBegin(&list);
    while( iter != ListEnd(&list) )
    {
        iter->data.val *= 3; // triple values to 3, 6, 9, 12
        if( iter->data.val % 2 )
            iter = ListErase( &list, iter ); // remove odd, now 6, 12
        else
            iter = iter->next;
    }

    buffer[0] = str[0] = 0;

    iter = ListBegin(&list);
    while( iter != ListEnd(&list) )
    {
        sprintf( str, "%d ", iter->data.val ); // print
        strcat(buffer,str); // and concatenate
        iter = iter->next;
    }

    ListDelete( &list );

    return buffer; // this should return "6 12 "
}
```

Comment: thanks for all the input. I've taken many points to heart, and have an updated version here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38ac37bcbce8d389

Comment: Feel free to post another question with the updated code for a new review.

Answer (score 7):

A few aspects regarding coding style and layout:

- In C you don't have to cast from `void*` to `T*`, so don't do it, it is just redundant code. Don't cast the result value of `malloc()`:

  ```
  lst->sentry = malloc( sizeof(Sentry) );
  ```

  I should note however, that if you plan on making C code compilable as C++, then the casts are absolutely necessary. If this is the case, disregard this point.
- When using the `sizeof` operator, it is better to apply it to the variable in question, rather than the type. Taking as an example the allocation of `Node` in `ListInsert()`, suppose you change the type of node to some other thing (a `NodeEx` or something), but keep the old `Node` struct around. If you happen to forget to update the use of `Node` in `malloc( sizeof(Node) )` and type sizes differ, you are in for a bad time. If you use the variable instead, this category of maintenance problems just goes away. So this can facilitate and simplify maintenance:

  ```
  Node* item = malloc( sizeof(*item) );
  ```
- You never check the return value of `malloc()`! Programs can run out of memory. You should always check the return value of `malloc`, `calloc` and friends to at least print a message log if allocation fails. As it is now, if the program were to run out of memory, it would crash with very little to no information about the error.
- When we are talking about sizes and lengths, [`size_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/size_t/?kw=size_t) is the type of choice, rather than `int`. Consider making `List::size` a `size_t`.
- At the moment, none of the pointers your functions receive are being validated. Since this is a tutorial, it should be a good opportunity to introduce the use of [`assert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) for function parameter validation.
- This `lst->size += 1;` and `lst->size -= 1;` are fine, but the `++` and `--` operators are the most idiomatic way of incrementing and decrementing by one in C, so the readers of your tutorial should start seeing it from early because that's how 99% of the C code they'll read is going to be written.
- Tiny inconsistency with spacing here `lst->sentry=0;` inside `ListDelete()`. Make sure to put spaces between arithmetical operators and assignments.

Answer (score 5):

- `ListIntegrityCheck` is very optimistic. If the integrity is broken, you may encounter a bad `next` pointer, or - even worse - the loop may become infinite. I would recommend to make a `for (sz = 0; sz < lst->size; sz++)` loop instead.
- A `don't call for end` comment on `ListErase` is a red flag. Better make it to test that the node is OK to be erased, and perhaps return NULL if it is not. Same applies for `Pop` functions.
- `ListErase` returns a pointer, `Pop` return nothing. Looks a bit inconsistent. I'd rather let them `return ListErase();`